# Rails 4.0 email addrese issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, overriding

Well I decided to try a different approach. Right now I have pages that are only accessible by number ids instead of usernames or emails. I would like it to be accessible by email addreses instead. I tried to override them but it failed in rails 4.0 and I tried the find_by_email command which also failed. This is the error message that I get:   ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in AccountsController#show.
The only method that did work is find(params[:id]) which only works for accounts that have id's attached them and fails completly if it is null.

Is there any other method to solve this?

Rails Controller

```
   def show
      #puts "****************************************"
      #puts params
      if @account.nil?
         render "shared/404"
      else
         #if !current_account.nil?
            respond_with @account
         #else
         #   render "shared/403"
         #end
      end



def load_findaccount
     #params[:id] remains fixed but find_by_id changes to username
     @account = Account.find(params[:id])
     #user_path(user)
```

Account.rb

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
   #def to_param  # overridden
   #   email
   #end

   validates :first_name, :presence => true
   validates :last_name, :presence => true
   validates :email, :presence => true, :uniqueness =>{:case_sensitive => false}
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to resolve this on my own and use just Rails 3.2. So this will end it for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `Account.where(:email => "example@pop.com")`. This will retrieve the records for that email id which I think will be at max one record in your code as email id is unique in your model.

Comment: That was kind of nice idea to try but for some reason it didn't work. It is now showing an undefined method `email' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation in the views part now.

Comment: @user1879925 pardon me, I have edited the answer why don't you try this one.

Comment: I tried it but didn't work. Rails 4 is not up to speed yet to do what I need.